# Getting Stuck in a while loop

Tags: python

I can't get past the `while` statement:

```
letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
while letter_grade!="A" or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F":
    print ("Enter a valid letter")
    letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
```

Comment: Can you please provide the error.

Comment: `letter_grade!="A" or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F"` is equivalent to `letter_grade!="A" or True or True or True or True or True or True`

Comment: there is no error message whenever i enter any of these letter it repeats the loop even tho it should move on with the code

Comment: Change `letter_grade!="A" or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F":` to `while letter_grade not in ["A", "B+", "B", "C+", "C", "D", "F"]:`

Comment: @aylianesc a set would be more appropriate in this case. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
while letter_grade not in ["A","B+","B","C+","C","D","F"]:
    print ("Enter a valid letter")
    letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
```

Your current code doesn't work since you can't simplify boolean statements like you have. To make what you have work you would have to change it to:

```
letter_grade!="A" and letter_grade!="B+" and #etc.
```

where you have to test every letter against the variable.

Comment: Care to share what was wrong with his code?

Comment: @everton 
`while letter_grade!="A" or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F"` here all the character/string represents True i.e. or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F" which was causing infinite while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not understand how logical statements work. Your line is defined as:

```
while letter_grade!="A" or "B+" or "B" or "C+" or "C" or "D" or "F":
```

This always returns true since it does not mean what you want it to be. You wanted to use something like that:

```
while letter_grade!="A" and letter_grade!="B+" and letter_grade!="B": #etc
```

But for readability, I would recommend that code :

```
letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
possible_grades = {"A","B+","B","C+","C","D","F"}
while letter_grade not in possible_grades:
    print ("Enter a valid letter")
    letter_grade=input("What is your letter grade(please use capitlization): ")
```

Note that using a set will allow faster lookup.